# Higher Segmented Control for ios 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm using this code to change the Segmented Control height. It works perfect for 8.0 and newest versions but not with lower like 7.1. Do you know any other way to change it? Thanks!

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:segmentedControlShortcuts
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:nil
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                             multiplier:1
                                                               constant:50];
```

That's the error that i receive in 7.1:

"2015-04-09 12:10:06.626 KMetrix[546:607] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Tested in both iOS7 & iOS8 -

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.mySegmentCtrl
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:nil
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                             multiplier:1
                                                               constant:50];
[self.mySegmentCtrl addConstraint:constraint];
```

Check screenshots it works in both iOS7 & iOS8 -

[image]

[image]

Comment: It works when on the Interface Builder and on the Preview but after when i run the application it doesn't

Comment: It works perfect for version 8.0 but not for 7.1. Every time I interact with it the size of the segmented control changes.

Comment: I updated the question, look at the error showed under the code

Comment: see this error is due to constraint you might have added in storyboard. By looking at the error I cant figure out which constraint its failing but I guess you have added height constraint for segment control value of which will be 29 (constant) and relation equal. But ideally in this case it has to be greater than equal. so check this and fix. it will be good if you don't provide height constraint.

Comment: Wow, can't find it.... Will i fix it if I delete the segmented control and I add the code to the new one?

Comment: yes you can try this. delete the segmented control add new one and take IBOutlet of this.

Comment: Yes, your code works perfect, but now I need to correct the problem that I have now. Thanks for your time.